# IOS : fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value (lldb)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let user = MadhouseUser.allObjects().firstObject() as! MadhouseUser
        DatabaseModel.passionTitles.removeAll()
```

It shows error:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
>       (lldb) Thread 1:EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)”

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like allObjects() is empty.
Try this

```
let user = MadhouseUser.allObjects().firstObject() as? MadhouseUser
```

and check if the user is nil.